# SSIS pulling data from Oracle

Tags: oracle, ssis

I have an SSIS package that is pulling data from an oracle database using the Native OLD DB\Oracle provider for OLD DB.
My package successfully but slowly pulls the data from one view in Oracle to a staging table in my SQL Database.  The problem I am having is some of fields in Oracle are 4000 char in length and in SQL Server I only need the first 255 characters.  Would it be better to do a substring in my query for the oracle and only take the size i need, or to take all 4000 characters?  Is there a better way to handle this data import?

here is a sample of the query I am using to extract the data from Oracle:

```
select a
, b
, c
, substring (c,1,255) as c, substring (d,1,255) as d
, e
,   CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR from LAST_TAKEN_DT) < 1900
        THEN NULL 
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR from LAST_TAKEN_DT) > 2025
        THEN NULL
    END AS LAST_TAKEN_DT
```

from oracle_View1

Comment: the case statement is because the last_taken_dt field in oracle is a test field and going into the SQL Server it is a datetime field.

Comment: Yes it's generally better to reduce the dataset as early as possible. That includes width as well as rowcount.

Answer (score 1):

First off if it was upto you I would suggest using the Attunity Oracle adapters over the OLEDB connection. It is definitely a lot faster and you could choose to do the substring in the Oracle query or within your SSIS package using a derived column.

Comment: +1 for Attunity.  I always SUBTRING or CAST every column to the output requirements - this also insulates you from seemingly trivial datatype changes that can break SSIS, e.g. Oracle column increases from VARCHAR2(30) to VARCHAR2(60).